# Counterexample for intersection of polar sets is not the closed convex hill of union of polar sets?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $A,B$ be two subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n,$ let $A^\circ$ denote the polar set of $A,$ i.e.
$$A^\circ=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n|\ \sup_{y\in A}\langle x,y\rangle\leq 1\},$$
where $\langle-,-\rangle$ is the standard inner product of $\mathbb{R}^n.$
If $A,B$ are closed convex set which contains the origin, then
$$(A\cap B)^\circ $$
is the closed convex hull of $A^\circ \cup B^\circ.$

Now I want to know are there any examples which show that the conclusion is not true in general.

Comment: There is an issue with the title your question. Look carefully

Comment: Thanks, I have corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about this construction a priori, but if I understand it correctly then you can take singleton sets $A=\{(0,1)\}$ and $B=\{(0,2)\}$ in $\mathbb{R^2}$. The polar set of $A \cap B=\emptyset$ is the whole plane, but the union of the polar sets is only $\mathbb R \times (-\infty, 1]$.

Comment: Thanks, it is a great.